# Android paging GridView/ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I was looking for a library or some help wrapping my head around some code. I need a GridView or ListView that kind of behaves like a ViewPager, but will display as many items as it can on each swipe. Basically, if I have 300 items, and I can only display 5 at a time, I want to be able to swipe down and display 5, and then display the next 5 on the next swipe. I'm sure it's possible, but how would I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

Basically, I set up a normal GridView (with ~300 items) and scroll programmatically when you click on it. I had to use OnItemClick because you can't use regular OnClick listeners with AdapterView (GridView, ListView, etc)

```
View.OnTouchListener gridDisableScroll = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener gridClickScroll = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(((GridView)adapterView).getLastVisiblePosition()
                         == adapterView.getAdapter().getCount()-1) {
                     //if you're at the bottom, scroll to the top!
                     ((GridView)adapterView).smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                } else {
                    //scroll down the distance of the height of the GridView
                    ((GridView) adapterView).smoothScrollBy(adapterView.getMeasuredHeight(), 700);//700ms
                    //may not be necessary...force draw after scrolling
                    adapterView.invalidate();
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView, set a scroll listener with `setOnScrollListener` class. Then, in your scroll listener, handle the method `onScroll`:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // ...
}
```

Notice you have the parameters to determine if user has scrolled to the bottom -if so, load the next page of items and add them to your adapter.

Comment: The issue is that it is already loaded. I want to be able to display as much as the user can see, and then scroll down and it'll automatically snap to another set of items, up to what the user can see. Does it make more sense now?